# MYSQL/PHP sum with group by

Tags: php, mysql, sql

tableA 
id B_id C_id 
1  1        0 
2  1        0
3  0        1
4  0        2
5  0        2
6  0        2
tableB 
id amount quantity
 
1    10         2

tableC
id amount quantity 
1   6            1 
2  15          3

I have this kind of database and I know it is not structured very well because I only continued this website and I wasn't given much time to restructure the website.

My question is how can i get the total amount of tableB and tableC using a LEFT JOIN of the two tables to tableA. As you can see the quantity in tableB and tableC will make the same number of tableA record. I was able to get each of the transactions amount using this code:

`SELECT * 
FROM tableA A
LEFT JOIN tableB B ON A.id = B.id
LEFT JOIN tableC C ON C.id = A.id
GROUP BY B.id, C.id`

It would return:
`id B_id C_id B.id B.amount B. quantity C.id C.amount C.quantity
 1  1    0    1    10        2           0    0        0

 3  0    1    0    0         0           1    6        1
 4  0    2    0    0         0           2    15       3`

but now I want to get the total using mysql SUM but GROUP BY cannot be used with the aggregate function SUM so the total should be: 10+6+15 = 31

Comment: `GROUP BY cannot be used with the aggregate function SUM`.... yes it can! Please explain.... show actual SQL query that you tried using SUM and GROUP BY, and the exact error message that you got

Comment: SELECT (SUM(B.amount)+SUM(C.amount)) AS total<br>
FROM tableA A<br>
LEFT JOIN tableB B ON A.id = B.id<br>
LEFT JOIN tableC C ON C.id = A.id<br>
GROUP BY B.id, C.id<br>

Comment: Can you edit the question and include the results that you want?

Comment: If you want to GROUP BY B.id, C.id, then they need to be selected columns: `SELECT B.id, C.id, SUM(B.amount)+SUM(C.amount)) AS total FROM tableA A LEFT JOIN tableB B ON A.id = B.id LEFT JOIN tableC C ON C.id = A.id GROUP BY B.id, C.id`.... if you don't need them as selected columns, don't GROUP BY them, `SELECT SUM(B.amount)+SUM(C.amount)) AS total FROM tableA A LEFT JOIN tableB B ON A.id = B.id LEFT JOIN tableC C ON C.id = A.id`

Comment: There's no error showing but the result i wanted is not what is displayed by the query. I want to get the SUM of all AMOUNT of tableB and table C. So it should be total: 31

Comment: If you want the grand total, then don't use GROUP BY.... use GROUP BY only if you want "subtotals"

Comment: yeah group by is not giving off the answer i wanted I have edited my question thank you for your answers.

Comment: I think you shuld just start over, with a better design.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT coalesce(sum(b.quantity), 0) + coalesce(sum(c.quantity), 0)
FROM tableA A LEFT JOIN
     tableB B
     ON A.id = B.id LEFT JOIN
     tableC C
     ON C.id = A.id;
```

This returns the total across the two tables.

EDIT:

If you just want the sum of tables b and c, what is table a for?  Is this what you want?

```
select amountb + amountc
from (select sum(amount) as amountb from tableb) b cross join
     (select sum(amount) as amountc from tablec) c;
```

Comment: i want to get the SUM of the B.amount and C.amount I have edited my question thanks you for the answer